# setting selection for multiple items in a QTreeView

Tags: pyqt4

So I've been using :

```
treeView.setCurrentIndex( index )
```

to set the active item in my treeView.  But if I have an array of item indices that I would like to select, how do I add to my currently selected item?

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [QTreeView](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qtreeview.html) doesn't have as many bundled methods as a QTreeWidget, so you have to drop down to the other components for some functionality. In this case, you might want to use the [SelectionModel](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qitemselectionmodel.html#select).

```py
selModel = treeView.selectionModel()
for idx in indexList:
    selModel.select(idx, selModel.Select)
```

Comment: So I tried your solution but it didn't seem to add to the currently selected.

Comment: I changed it to use Select instead of SelectCurrent and it works now.  Thx!

Comment: Awesome. Sorry about that. Sometimes I forget the right [flag](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qitemselectionmodel.html#SelectionFlag-enum) without directly trying it